# Nodes.org install sur local src node

Tags: nodejs

I  am installing nodes the command `sudo ./configure` is ok but when I type next command `menudo make` I got an error g++ and 127 .

How could I resolve them to finish the nodes installation

Answer (score 0):

Test if the following command helps:

```
sudo sh ./configure
```

Then run the the second command as sudo, and use sh ([what's sh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280208/whats-the-difference-between-sudo-command-and-sudo-sh-command)):

```
sudo sh menudo make
```

If not, try to fully update your system. If an update doesn't work, then please write your question more extensive, and include what the sudo ./configure gives you as well as the menudo make.