# Need help creating a persistent live usb, can any one help?

Tags: partitioning, live-usb

I was able to create a ext3 partition with out any problems using Gparted and now I am trying to send over a persistence.conf but it fails each time, here is what commands I am running:

```
 sudo mkdir /mnt/usb
 sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/usb
 sudo echo "/ union" >> /mnt/usb/persistence.conf
 bash: /mnt/usb/persistence.conf: Permission denied
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There is [a post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138356/how-do-i-get-a-live-usb-to-use-a-partition-for-persistence) with detailed answer, explaining how to create Live USB with persistent partition.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo echo "something" > etc` never works, better try this 
`sudo sh -c "echo ...."`, the working command should be like this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo "/ union" > persistence.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Bash shell in Sudo mode with `-c` option to execute the custom shell.

```
sudo bash -c "echo '/ union' > /mnt/persist/persistence.conf"
```

Also note that you should properly nest the double quotes.

Another example is:

```
sudo bash -c "cat /mnt/persist/persistence.conf"
```

Reference: 
[What's the difference between 'sudo [command]' and 'sudo sh [command]?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280208/whats-the-difference-between-sudo-command-and-sudo-sh-command)

Answer (score 0):

This is a clean way of writing files with sudo.

```
echo "/ union" | sudo tee persistence.conf
```