# Why script with /bin/bash is working, with /bin/sh not?

Tags: bash, scripts

My friend asked me why this two simple script are not working in both shells:

Test File "abc.txt":

```
aaa
111
bbb
111
ccc
111
ddd
```

Script #1 (a):

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing $line"
done < <(grep 111 abc.txt)
```

Output:

```
./a: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./a: line 4: `done < <(grep 111 abc.txt)'
```

Script #2 (b):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing $line"
done < <(grep 111 abc.txt)
```

Output:

```
Processing 111
Processing 111
Processing 111
```

I checked bash and sh on my machine and if I understand this correct this is the same thing.

/bin/sh is just a link to /bin/bash:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 938736 May 10  2012 bash
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      4 Feb 13 10:20 sh -> bash
```

Can someone explain me where is the difference?

Comment: difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because Bash behaves differently when `$0` is `sh`.

From [Bash's behaviour    [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashbehaviour#sh_mode):

> ### SH mode
>
> When Bash starts in SH compatiblity mode, it tries to mimic the
>   startup behaviour of historical versions of `sh` as closely
>   as possible, while conforming to the POSIX® standard as well. The
>   profile files read are `/etc/profile` and
>   `~/.profile`, if it's a login shell.
>
> If it's not a login shell, the environment variable ENV is evaluated and the resulting
>   filename is taken as name of the startup file.
>
> After the startup files are read, Bash enters the [POSIX(r)
>   compatiblity mode (for running, not for
>   starting!)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashbehaviour#posix_run_mode).
>
> **Bash starts in `sh` compatiblity
>   mode when:**
>
> - the base filename in
>     `argv[0]` is `sh` (Attention dear uber-clever
>     Linux users… `/bin/sh` may be linked to
>     `/bin/bash`, but that doesn't mean it acts like
>     `/bin/bash`)

More information can be found at the [Bash Reference Manual: Bash POSIX Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html), specifically:

> - Process substitution is not available.

which is why your `sh` script is failing, as the `<(..)` syntax is using process substitution.

Answer (score 1):

According to

```
man bash
```

it says

```
When invoked as sh, bash enters posix mode after the startup files are read.
```

So you can not use bash features when run your script with `/bin/sh`.