# Clearsigned file isn't valid, from 01.org package?

Tags: apt, intel-graphics, gnupg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I have an HD 4600 integrated graphics chip.

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

Intel just released the new version of their Graphics driver for Ubuntu 14.04.
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux

When I try to install it, I get stuck at:

```
Finished : E:GPG error: http://download.01.org trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)  [  ] ◦
main-window.c/on_transaction_finished: Package transaction finished with an error
```

And it prevents `sudo apt-get update` from completing. I get the same error as before.

I went to **Software & Updates** and under **Other Software** tab I removed the bad repository: `http://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main`, and then I could update my repositories. But I cannot install the Intel Graphics Driver!

I hope I'm making sense. This is the first day this is available, so I'm counting on Intel to fix this soon, if not, I hope someone can help find a work around.

Comment: wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -

Comment: wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | sudo apt-key add -

Comment: I'll try these out, thanks. Although I'm pretty sure I've tried these before.

Comment: leave it its same here E:GPG error: http://download.01.org trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Comment: Ok, up to Intel to fix?

Comment: Up to intel is already done, see this thread : [Graphics Installer 1.0.5 for Linux* released!](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/331)

Comment: Posted the new thread https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/331

Comment: The above didn't work for me. I also tried saving prior to clicking install (rather than fast-switching and saving), and just going to software and updates and manually editing the link there. I got the same error each time. :/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The installer contains the wrong repository url. To fix this you need:

1. Start the installer and try to install, you got error, close installer.
2. Open console and type:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list
   ```
3. Replace text with text below, **don't close gedit just leave it**:

   ```
   deb https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/ trusty main #Intel Graphics drivers
   ```
4. Start the installer again, press Begin button, press Install button and fast switch to gedit and **hold** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

   `sudo apt-get update` may yield:

   ```
   GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366
   ```

   Fix it with:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A902DDA375E52366
   ```

Comment: Had to try it a few times to get it to work, but it does indeed do the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, something to add, "apt-get update" yielded: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366

So I fixed it with:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A902DDA375E52366

Comment: Failed to fetch http://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-gpu-tools/intel-gpu-tools_1.6-1_amd64.deb Size mismatch

Comment: I think form mine I had to hit save right as it showed "Setting up Repositories" otherwise I think holding it down hit a repeat limit or something.

Comment: adding a key with *apt-key adv* is considered a security risk. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195579 see here http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch7.en.html#s-deb-pack-sign

Answer (score 2):

Here's the easier solution for those with problems:

1. Open Nautilus(file explorer), go to Edit -> Preferences -> Behavior, and make sure that under **Executable text files**, **Ask each time** is selected! (if not, select it)
2. Close the window
3. Open Nautilus (if not already open)
4. Right click **New document > Empty document**
5. Name it script.sh
6. Open it and enter this:

   ```bsh
   #! /bin/bash
   while [ 1 ]; do
       sudo sed --in-place 's/http:/https:/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list
       sleep 1
   done
   ```
7. Save it and close it
8. Right click on `script.sh` and select **Permissions**
9. Check **Allow executing this file as program**
10. Close the window
11. Double click it
12. Select **Run in terminal**
13. Enter password
14. **DO NOT** close the terminal
15. Begin installation, and everything should work

I also got **Failed to fetch download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/… Size mismatch** error and this fixed the problem. You can delete script file and close the terminal when the installation is finished.

Edit: There is simpler way:

1. Enter this in terminal:

   ```bsh
   #! /bin/bash
   while [ 1 ]; do
       sudo sed --in-place 's/http:/https:/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list
       sleep 1
   done
   ```
2. Enter password
3. Run the installer

Comment: you can as well just paste that in shell :)

Comment: Should it be "#!/bin/sh" instead of "#!/bin/bash"? I'm sure it will run either way, I'm just asking because I don't know the answer.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the difference too.

Comment: Functionally, [there is no difference](http://askubuntu.com/a/141932/2079) between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Use gdebi to install the intel-linux-graphics-installer and you won't have the GPG problems. It should automatically install with the deb package. Use the following commands to do so:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gdebi
cd && wget https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.6-0intel1_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.6-0intel1_amd64.deb
intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Follow the instructions displayed in the GUI to update your system. Save any unsaved work and reboot for the changes to take effect.

---

Furthermore, using

```
sudo apt-key adv
```

Is considered a security risk and is not recommended as you are *"undermining the whole security concept as this is not a secure way of recieving keys for various reasons (like: hkp is a plaintext protocol, short and even long keyids can be forged, …)"*. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195579

I believe the correct way is to first import the key

```
GET https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg | gpg --import
```

Check the fingerprint

```
gpg --check-sigs --fingerprint 75E52366
```

Get the key from the keyserver

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 7CB0FA13
```

Export the key to your keyring

```
gpg -a --export 75E52366 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Repeat for second key

```
GET https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 | gpg --import

gpg --check-sigs --fingerprint 2F4AAA66

gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 144BD458

gpg -a --export 2F4AAA66 | sudo apt-key add -
```

more info http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch7.en.html#s-deb-pack-sign