# How to install graphics drivers off a live usb

Tags: boot, grub2, intel-graphics

Hi im having some trouble with Xubuntu. I have a toshiba satellite c50-b-14d (Hardware can be found here: http://www.toshiba.co.uk/laptops/satellite/c50-b/satellite-c50-b-14d/) After installing Xubuntu everytime I boot I get a small white dash/underscore on a black screen. I suspected this may be a grub error at first but after installing grub from a live usb there has been no difference. I suspect it may be my graphics drivers.

Can somebody tell me how I can install them from a live usb to my HDD? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the drivers directly from Intel [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux). This should correctly install the drivers for you.

Some users have reported an issue with the URL of the repository the installer adds to your system. To fix it see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466197/14-04-intel-graphics-installer-1-0-5-clearsigned-file-isnt-valid#comment616085_466197).

Comment: This hasn't changed anything. Can somebody tell me if what i've got is actaully a graphics driver error or is it an issue with grub?

Comment: If reinstalling the driver had no effect then it would seem that it is a problem with grub. You may need to reinstall and use manual disk partitioning. More information can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/partitioning)