# Error message 'source: not found' when running a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am creating a little automated setup script that will modify `/etc/profile` and `$HOME/.profile` if some paths are not exported. Then, I'd like to reload these automatically.

I have read that `source` does this, so I fired up my terminal and entered:

```
source /etc/profile
source ~/.profile
```

From the terminal, it didn't output any error.

However, putting these two commands inside the Bash script results in `source: not found`.

1. How can I be sure that the script is executed by Bash, even if `#!/bin/sh` is specified (apparently, it does not guarantee it)?
2. Why would it say that these two sources cannot be found when they are unmistakably there?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is not `bash`. To execute your script with `bash`, write `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in your script.

The error `source: not found` is not dropped, because `/etc/profile` is not found. It's dropped, because `source` is not found. `source` is a Bash built-in function, and you don't execute the script with `bash`. So it's clear why it is not found. Change the `#!` line in the script, and it will work.

Answer (score 34):

Some shells support `.` instead of `source`. So you can try something like this

```
. filename
```

instead of

```
source filename
```

Hope it works

Comment: This was edited to claim that csh supports `.` and sh supports `source`, but that edit was wrong and it has since been rolled back. The reverse is true: csh and tcsh support `source`, POSIX shells (sh) support `.`, and some POSIX-style shells (like bash) support both. I'm mentioning this because you had approved the edit and might otherwise wonder why it was rolled back. If you *really* want to say what the edit said, you can roll back the rollback--though that would make this answer wrong. (If you want this post to be more detailed, I think it would be better to do a new edit.)

Comment: this worked for me, but I had to fully qualify the path to filename, so `. ./filename` instead of just `. filename`

Answer (score 14):

> **1. How can I be sure that the script is executed by Bash, even if
>    `#!/bin/sh` is specified (apparently, it does not guarantee it)?**

To be sure that a script written for `sh` shell (as in your case - see [What is difference between #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/141928/147044)) is executed by Bash, just run the following command:

```
bash script_name
```

Thus, you will not get that error anymore.

> **2. Why would it say that these two sources cannot be found when they are
>   unmistakably there?**

It doesn't say that those sourced files are not there. It says that the `source` command is not found. This is normal, because since you start your script with `#!/bin/sh` line, your script will run using `sh` and not `bash` as you may think. Why is it normal? Because `source` command is a Bash builtin, but not a `sh` builtin. To source a file in `sh`, you should use `.` (dot). Example:

```
. /etc/profile
. ~/.profile
```

Another way is to change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` as [chaos](https://askubuntu.com/users/185729/chaos) said in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/504549/147044).

Answer (score 9):

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702425/source-command-not-found-in-sh-shell):

> `/bin/sh` is usually some other shell trying to mimic The Shell. Many distributions use `/bin/bash` for `sh`, it supports source. On Ubuntu, though, `/bin/dash` is used which does not support source. If you cannot edit the script, try to change the shell which runs it.