# What are syntax differences between bash and dash?

Tags: bash, scripts, dash-shell

I just realized that in current Ubuntu version `/bin/sh` is no more symlinked to `bash` (as it used to be for many years), but to `dash` instead. I wonder what are the actual syntax differences between those two shells and how big is the probability that a shell script written with `bash` in mind won't work under `dash`. Can anybody point me to a good and clear description of differences between these two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the point of sh being linked to dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976485/what-is-the-point-of-sh-being-linked-to-dash)

Comment: [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) is a good start; a more thorough reference for a POSIX compliant shell is [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6: Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

Comment: @Nmath: None of the answers there does clearly specify differences between those shells. What I would like is some form of a detailed list of `bash` commands or other syntax features that are not supported in `dash`.

Comment: Don't know about dash, but at least the root user should initially have a shell with very minimal requirements to hardware and software. In case of emergency, a *fat* shell might not be able to even start up.

Comment: how about https://lwn.net/Articles/343924/ ?

Comment: Don't know dash, but use fish and most bash commands work.  Most differences are when combining commands with &&.  Probably a few others.

Comment: FYI if you want to test a particular script for sh/POSIX compatibility, the `devscripts` package provides a `checkbashisms` script for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-the-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash)

Comment: @KK Patel the link you specified is totally unrelated to my question. I obviously understand that bash and dash are two different shells. I was asking about the exact set of syntax differences.

Answer (score 8):

A simple rule of thumb is: if your script was written in bash, do not assume it will work in dash. A full list of differences is beyond the scope of a simple Q&A, but essentially, `dash` is a POSIX shell, so it implements what is described in the [POSIX specification for the shell language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) *and only that*.

Here are the common bashisms I most often fall afoul of:

- `[[`: the `[[ condition ]]` construct isn't supported by `dash`, you need to use `[ ]` instead.
- `==` : to test if two values are equal, use `=` in dash since `==` is not supported.
- `source`: the POSIX command for sourcing a script is `.`. The `source` builtin is a bash alias to the standard `.`, so always use `. file` instead of `source file`.
- `shopt`: this is a bash builtin that sets certain non-standard options. Not supported by `dash`.
- `$RANDOM`: this is set to a random number on each use in `bash`, but doesn't work in `dash`.

By far the most common problem is the lack of `[[` support. You can find a more comprehensive list on the Ubuntu Wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

Comment: as a supplementation, 'function' is a keyword in bash to declare a function but not available in dash. check description here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917018/what-is-the-function-keyword-used-in-some-bash-scripts

Comment: Believe it or not, until today I've been Google searching for bourne shell instead of dash any time I'm trying to find supported syntax by `/bin/sh`